# Capitalized words in navigation for phone app

Tags: navigation, text, font

I read that capitalized text reduces reading speed, but does it apply to navigation text?

For example, at the top of the app I would have 3 navigation elements:

HOME BOOKMARK SETTINGS

Will it affect user experience negatively in anyway? Is using title case better? e.g Home Bookmark Setting

I was thinking it would grab user's attention when they first launch the app

Answer (score 1):

Both Apple design guidelines and Android design guideline do not promote ALL CAPS. As a user, I prefer to see Title case or Line Case in the app and find ALL CAPS hard to read. 
I do see an exception in iOS camera app where  ALL CAPS is used!

Link to article regarding the comparison of the case: https://medium.com/@jsaito/making-a-case-for-letter-case-19d09f653c98
This article has a good comparison of the case used in iOS and Android and might be useful for you.

Further reading links :

Apple design guideline: https://developer.apple.com/design

Android design guideline: https://material.io/design/introduction/